# Tell Command Line to run Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python file but when I attempt to run it on my command line it wants to run it using Python 2.
I have `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as the first line of code but it still wants to run it using Python 2.  If it helps I'm on OSX.

Comment: try "python3" as command, worked for me a while ago

Comment: Use _python3_ command to run file using python3.

Comment: how do you run this program?

Comment: How are you invoking the command?

Comment: I was running it as `python filename.py`

Comment: Run `which python3` and then put that path on the shebang line, or just use `python3 filename.py`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html

Comment: Great! `python3` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either,

1. Use `python3 filename.py`, or
2. Create an alias. Add `alias python=python3` in `~/.bash_profile`, run `source ~/.bash_profile`, and then `python filename.py` should invoke python3, or
3. Run `which python3`, copy the path and add it at the top of your script as the shebang line. For me, the command returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3`. It may be different for you, or
4. You can also use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), which supports multiple python environments simultaneously.